# e11000 duplicate key error collection in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am getting an index-0 duplicate key error code-11000 when I click the same post-action with the same data that is already saved. [VS Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztLfE.png)But I want to save the data more than once and not want to be unique.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So @Hasan, you have to remove `unique: true` from their dedicated model field after that you can add more than one time similar values in database